# find a user by model associations rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model Camera in which

```
belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => 'owner_id', :class_name => 'EvercamUser'
```

i have asscociation like this. when i do Camera.first

```
#<Camera id: 6, created_at: "2013-12-12 17:30:32", updated_at: "2015-11-19 10:19:33", exid: "dublin-rememberance-floor2", owner_id: 4, is_public: true
```

i can get owner id, is there any way to create such function that , along side getting owner id, i can get the data which linked with this id for example at id = 4

```
#<EvercamUser id: 4, created_at: "2013-12-12 16:43:46", updated_at: "2015-04-16 15:23:19", firstname: "Garrett", lastname: "Heaver", username: "garrettheaver"
```

this user is present, what if when i do Camera.first then instead of OnwerID, how can i get the owners Name? 
Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: `Camera.first.user.name` works for you?

Comment: Camera.first.owner.username

Comment: Both gave me error. Camera.first was example, what if i want Camera.all and then in this i want Owner Name instead of Owner id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how can i get the owners Name

You'd call the associative *object* on the `Camera` object:

```
@camera = Camera.find x
@user   = @camera.user
@user.name #-> outputs name of associated user object
```

... this will allow you to call the attributes of the child object on it: `@camera.user.name` or `@camera.user.email`, etc

---

Off topic, but I always include a reference to [`delegate`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Delegation) for this type of issue; it avoids the [law of demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) (where you're using more than one point to access data).

This would allow you to use:

```
#app/models/camera.rb
class Camera < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user, foreign_key: :owner_id, class_name: 'EvercamUser'
   delegate :name, to: :user, prefix: true #-> @camera.user_name
end

@camera = Camera.find x
@camera.user_name #-> outputs the user's name on the camera object (not user object)
```

---

To give you some context, Rails uses [`ActiveRecord`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern) to invoke/create objects for you.

In line with the [object orientated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) nature of Rails, ActiveRecord is known as an *ORM* (Object Relationship Mapper). This basically allows you to create an object through ActiveRecord, and if it is associated to another (as Rails does with its [associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)), it will append the associated object onto the parent.

Thus, when you're asking about calling `owner_id`, you're referring to the [`foreign_key`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) of the association (the database column which joins the two tables together):

[image]

What you need is to reference the associated *object*, which I've detailed above.

Comment: while going with delegate.
`NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for #<EvercamUser:0x007f031b1217e8>`

Comment: lol I'm sorry, I didn't look at the object you returned. You'll need to replace `:name` with either `:firstname`, `:lastname` or `:username` (it has to be available from your associated class)

Comment: actually thing is, am getting OBJECT = Camera.where(some conditions)
then rendering it to JS file as an json object from where i am appending data to rails view, e.g data[1].exid, data[1].id, i want it like that , data[1].user_firstname. it giving undefined

Comment: one more thing you didnt see that Users are coming from EvercamUser. not users.

Comment: Your question didn't mention json at all - it's a different implementation. The delegate uses the association name, not the class name. If you want to know about the json stuff, you should ask a new question; I answered what you asked and now you've changed the scope

Comment: Okay! you were talking about delegates that why i asked this anyhow what about EvercamUser?

Comment: What do you mean? The association name is what ActiveRecord uses to bind its objects to; the `EvercamUser` is the class name and won't matter to your associations :)

Answer (score 0):

What about using join here?

```
Camera.all.joins(:evercamusers)
Camera.where(:id => 1).joins(:users).first
```

Note: I'm a bit unsure if the correct parameter should be ":users" or ":evercamusers"

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/joins

You could also add methods to your class to do this.

```
class Camera < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => 'owner_id', :class_name => 'EvercamUser'

  def firstname
    self.user.firstname
  end
end
```

When you try to output data from Camera like this:

```
#<Camera id: 6, created_at: "2013-12-12 17:30:32", updated_at: "2015-11-19 10:19:33", exid: "dublin-rememberance-floor2", owner_id: 4, is_public: true
```

It won't show. But if you call the method like this, it should work:

```
Camera.first.firstname # "Garrett"
```

Also, if JSON is acceptable you could override the as_json method.

```
def as_json(options={})
  { :firstname => self.user.firstname }
end
```

Then call it with

```
Camera.first.as_json
```

If you need to do it with all, simply loop it

```
Camera.all.each { |c| puts c.firstname }
```

Comment: is there any way that i just edit Camera Model and these values come available to me?

Comment: I've updated the answer, hopefully it would help you.

Comment: what if i dont need it for first? 
what if i have done cam = Camera.all 
now i want cam.firstname? is it possible?

Comment: Camera.all is a Active Record Collection, and not a Model. You could do a loop. Camera.all.each { |c| puts c.firstname } 

If that's not good enough, you have to use join.